# Is there a Tcl extension to deal with huge lists, workaround the 2GB allocation limit?

Tags: tcl, allocation

Based a previous node in this site, [TCL max size of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314749/tcl-max-size-of-array) 
it would appear that Tcl cannot handle > 256M elements list. Is there an extension/future plan to overcome this limitation?
O/W, I would assume that for the time being, and next foreseeable future, if one needs to handle larger indexed arrays and/or dictionaries than that, one must resort to a different language.
Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I plan to fix the limitation as part of Tcl 9.0; I've done a few dry runs, so I know that it's a large but mostly mechanical change.

If you're dealing with very large amounts of data, consider putting it in a database. SQLite is recommended; it has an excellent Tcl API, and should be shipped as part of Tcl 8.6 (though that does depend on the packager; Linux distributions might make it be separate).

Comment: Thanks. When is TCL 9.0 due for release?